# Error while installing python library on Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to run a python script on VSCode and I need an additional library: ruamel.yaml. To install it, I'm writing in the terminal the following command: `pipenv install ruamel.yaml`. However, I receive the following error:

```
PS C:\Python> pipenv install ruamel.yaml
```

pipenv : The term 'pipenv' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1

- pipenv install ruamel.yaml
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (pipenv:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
  ```

How could I fix it? Thanks.

Comment: why dont you pip install instead of pipenv, or anaconda?

Comment: I thried, but I get the following error message: PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied

Comment: well you got administrative errors, i suggest seeing solutions online + did you actually installed anaconda?

Comment: @jules -How are things going? Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

VSCode uses PowerShell by default. Instead try switching to Command Prompt.

With a terminal windows open in VSCode, expand this drop down then "Select Default Shell".[image].

You can then select "Command Prompt". Remember to restart the terminal in VS Code. This will start a Command Prompt instead of PowerShell. Now try to use pip to install packages as normal.

Comment: Hello Jason. Thanks, but I'm getting the same errors...

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same situation:

[image]

The reason is that "pipenv" is not installed and the terminal cannot recognize this command. I installed it using "pip": `pip install pipenv`.

If the terminal also cannot recognize the pip command, it is recommended that you [install pip](https://pypi.org/project/pip/). However, the module installation tool "pip" is usually included in python.

pipenv install ruamel.yaml：

[image]

In addition, the terminal used in VS Code is integrated from the system's own terminal, so please make sure that the system terminal can be used.